# Android how to show and hide submenu items

Tags: java, android, menu

I'd like to create a togglable menu, when I click on the menu item it shows its submenus, and when I click again they should be hidden.

This is what I've got but they only get shown and I can't hide them again.

```
<group>
    <group>
        <item android:title="Menu 1" android:id="@+id/toggle" android:checkable="true" android:checked="false" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group1" android:visible="false">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sub_menu1"
            android:title="sub_menu1"
            >
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sub_menu2"
            android:title="sub_menu2"
            >
        </item>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sub_menu3"
            android:title="sub_menu3"
            >
        </item>
    </group>
</group>
```

and here is the java code

```
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case (R.id.toggle):
                if(menuItem.isChecked()){
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group1, true);
                    break;}
                else{
                    mNavigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.group1, false);
                    break;}
        }
    }
```

EDIT : i tried what wade suggested but stil no luck

```
case (R.id.toggle):

                    toogle= mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.toggle);
                    item1= mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item1);
                    item2 = mNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item2);

                    if (toogle.isChecked()) {
                        item1.setVisible(true);
                        item2.setVisible(true);
                        break;
                    }

                    else {
                        item1.setVisible(false);
                        item2.setVisible(false);
                        break;
                    }
```

if anyone got any other methodes or suggestions please do say them

Comment: I edited your post but left a trailing bracket after the if statement, so don't approve it or remove the bracket

Comment: There is a method called setVisible that accepts a boolean value and you can toggle the visibility of the MenuItem.

Comment: @Nathan Please do not make actual code changes in edits to questions. If you see a problem with the code, either post a comment or an answer if that is what is causing the OP's problem.

Comment: @WadeWilson can you be a bit more presice please.

Comment: @Asomuth on the MenuItem object there is a method called setVisible(boolean visible). When you want the menu item to hide search for the menu item and then call meuItem,setVisible(false). You pass in true when you want the menuItem to appear again.

Comment: @WadeWilson i tried what you said but still no luck, it only shows the items and doesnt hide them. Please do check the EDIT i made above.

Comment: @Asomuth have you debugged and stepped through the code to make sure it's executing.

Comment: @WadeWilson The code is working its just when i click on the Toggle Menutem again to hide the items, the item1 and item2 doesnt go invisible